# PHP action based on post ID

Tags: php, wordpress, post

We have an events page that redirects the user to a form when they click the booking button. I would like to add in a variable if the post is a specific ID but I can't get it to work correctly.
The current line in the page template

```
<form id="frmBooking" name="frmBooking" action="<?php echo site_url('/booking/'); ?>" method="post">
```

If the post is a specific ID I would like it to direct to a different page ( /redirect/ ) could you please help me out with this??

Comment: You want the action to be a different URL if there is a specific post ID? If so, what is the format of the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

```
<form id="frmBooking" name="frmBooking" action="<?php echo ( the_ID()  === 42  ? site_url('/redirect/') : site_url('/booking/') ); ?>" method="post">
```

This is known as a 'conditional expression'. If the first part evaluates to true (`the_ID()` returns '42' or whatever post-id you want to, `site_url('/redirect/')` will be used as the expressions result. Otherwise, the original one (`site_url('/booking/')` will be used